# is there anyway to convert from Double to BigInteger?

Tags: java, double, biginteger

Is there anyway to convert from `double` value to `BigInteger`?

```
double doubleValue = 64654679846513164.2;
BigInteger bigInteger = (BigInteger) doubleValue;
```

I try to cast it but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't understand the difference between an integer and a (floating point) double.

Comment: Or between conversion and casting.

Comment: Perhaps he wants a BigInteger containing 64654679846513164

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you want to store the integral part of the double into a `BigInteger`, then you can convert it into a `BigDecimal` and *then* into a `BigInteger`:

```
BigInteger k = BigDecimal.valueOf(doubleValue).toBigInteger();
```

Comment: If you actually want to take just the integral part of the double and store it in a BigInteger, this is surely the best answer?

Answer (score 18):

BigInteger is made for holding arbitrary precision integer numbers, not decimals. You can use the `BigDecimal` class to hold a double.

```
BigDecimal k = BigDecimal.valueOf(doublevalue);
```

In general, you cannot type cast a Java primitive into another class. The exceptions that I know about are the classes extending `Number`, such as the `Long` and `Integer` wrapper classes, which allow you to cast an int value into an Integer, and so on.

Comment: It would help to OP if you explain why type casting didn't work.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I added a thought about the casting, but not sure if it will answer OP's problem since he seems to be confused about more general things. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The process of converting a `Double` -> `BigDecimal` -> `BigInteger` is intensive. I propose the below: (about 500% faster)

```
BigInteger m = DoubleToBigInteger(doublevalue);

static BigInteger DoubleToBigInteger(double testVal) {
    long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(testVal); 
    int exp = ((int)(bits >> 52) & 0x7ff) - 1075;
    BigInteger m = BigInteger.valueOf((bits & ((1L << 52)) - 1) | (1L << 52)).shiftLeft(exp);
    return  (bits >= 0)? m : m.negate();
}
```