# Frege Double to Integer

Tags: java, haskell, casting, floor, frege

I would like to be able to convert a large `Double` to an `Integer`, but it seems that the Frege Haskell implementation of `floor` does not yield an `Integral` type. Instead, it seems to be implemented to interface with way Java does it, and takes a `Floating` type to a `Double`, `Floating r => r -> Double`. I could use `round`, but that rounds rather than truncate (though I might be able to subtract 0.5 and *then* round). I'd rather work without needing to resort to using `Int` or `Long`, which, as wide as the latter is, is still limited in precision.

Any way to go about flooring a floating point type to an arbitrary precision integer type?

Comment: Your subtraction approach sounds reasonable given the constraints, but I've never used Frege.

Comment: Judging from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960186/is-there-anyway-to-convert-from-double-to-biginteger one needs some itermediate representation  to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is indeed not available. The reason is that Java apparently doesn't offer methods that support it.

What you can do is to convert the (floored) double to a String and converting that to an Integer.

Here is an example:

```
frege> import Prelude.Math(floor)
frege> integerFromDouble d = String.aton ("%.0f".format (floor d))
function integerFromDouble :: Math.Floating a => a -> Integer
frege> integerFromDouble 987654321e20
98765432100000000000000000000
```

I wonder if there is a more effective method that somehow extracts the mantissa and exponent from a Double and computes the Integer.

Note that above function is unsafe because NaN, +Infinity and -Infinity exist:

```
frege> integerFromDouble (5/0)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Infinity"
```

You could either check that separately or replace `String.aton` with `String.integer` , which returns

```
Either NumberFormatException Integer
```

If you can make sure your computations don't exceed the `Long` capacity, what you want can be done with:

```
round . floor
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just call `intValue` on the `Double` result after calling `floor`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue%28%29

Comment: Apparently, OP uses numbers so big that not even Long is enough.