# Exact mixed comparison BigInteger and double in Java

Tags: java, comparison

Just noticed that Python and JavaScript have exact comparison.
Example in Python:

```
>>> 2**1023+1 > 8.98846567431158E307
True

>>> 2**1023-1 < 8.98846567431158E307
True
```

And JavaScript:

```
> 2n**1023n+1n > 8.98846567431158E307
true

> 2n**1023n-1n < 8.98846567431158E307
true
```

Anything similar available for Java, except converting both arguments to
BigDecimal?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17960186

Comment: Now that I've had a couple of hours to think about this, I'm fairly sure that the only ways to compare a `double` to `BigInteger` are to convert them both to `BigDecimal`, or to mess around fishing out sequences of bits.  The former is not as bad as it sounds, because there's very little overhead in converting `BigInteger` to `BigDecimal` - all the `BigDecimal` will be is a wrapper around the `BigInteger` that includes things like the scale and the precision.

Comment: Well, you can't really get around that overhead.  Even if you could convert your `double` directly to `BigInteger` for the comparison.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to convert the Java double floating point value into a rational number. But I don't know about some rational number integration into the JDK, would possibly need a 3rd party library.

Comment: You really wouldn't want to do that.  If you're going to compare the number to a BigInteger, you don't care about the fractional part of it.  But converting to a rational number and comparing forces you to multiply everything through by a potentially large power of two.

Comment: Power of two is only shifting. Thats still better than what BigDecimal would do. You can just record the power of two shifting, and defer it a little bit, so that you don't create unnecessarily some trivial bigint numbers like 2^n for some n.

Comment: I would be very surprised if you could find (or write) a library for rational numbers, that outperforms `BigDecimal` on comparing a `double` to a `BigInteger`.  The algorithm you've outlined in your answer would probably work well, but I don't see that it's in any way related to dealing with rational numbers.

Comment: You can convert a floating point value m*2^-n into the rational number m/2^n. You don't need to make it canonical for comparison. All you need some routines to unpack the the Java double floating point value. And there exists the routine Double.doubleToLongBits() for that purpose. The rest is bit masking and bit shifting to unpack the floating point value. So there is no need to wait for a library, the runtime of Java already supports unpacking.

Answer (score 0):

Preliminary answer, i.e. verbal solution sketch:

I am skeptical about a solution that would convert
to BigDecimal, since this conversion results in
a shift of the base from base=2 to base=10. As soon
as the exponent of the Java double floating point value
is different from the binary precision, this leads to additional digits and lengthy
pow() operations, which one can verify by inspecting
some open source BigDecimal(double)
constructor implementation.

One can get the mantissa via Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d).
If the Java double floating point value is not a sub-normal
all that needs to be done is (raw & DOUBLE_SNIF_MASK) +
(DOUBLE_SNIF_MASK+1) where 0x000fffffffffffffL This means
the integer Java primitive type long should be enough to
carry the mantissa. The challenge is now to perform a comparison
taking the exponent of the float also into account.

But I must admit I didn't have time yet to work
out some Java code. I have also in mind some
optimizations using bigLength() of the other
argument, which is in this setting a BigInteger.
The use of bitLength() would speed up the comparison.
A simple heuristic can implement a fast path, so that
the mantissa can be ignored. Already the exponent
of the double and the bitLength() of the BigInteger
give enough information for a comparison result.

As soon as I have time and a prototype running, I might
publish some Java code fragment here. But maybe somebody
faced the problem already. My general hypothesis is that a fast or
even ultra fast routine is possible. But I didn't have
much time to search the internet and to find an
implementation, thats why I defered the problem to
stack overflow, maybe somebody else had the same
problem as well and/or might point to a complete solution?